# Is there an efficient way of subtracting an element from rest of the elements of the list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to subtract each element of the list from the rest of the elements, I have been using nested loop code:

```
list_ = [1,2,3,4,5]
out = []
for i in range(len(list_)):
    s = 0
    for j in range(i,len(list_)):
        s += list_[i] - list_[j]
    out.append(s)
```

And output is:

```
[-10, -6, -3, -1, 0]
```

I require this computation for my algorithm, and it's O(n^2) of complexity slows it down.

I appreciate the reader for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that is O(n).

```
list_ = [1,2,3,4,5]
total = sum(list_)
length = len(list_)
acc = 0
out = []
for i, v in enumerate(list_):
    acc += v
    result = v*(length-(i+1)) - (total - acc)
    out.append(result)
```

Result

```
>>> out
[-10, -6, -3, -1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension with `enumerate`, `sum` and `len`

```
list_ = [1,2,3,4,5]
print([v * len(list_[i:]) - sum(list_[i:]) for i, v in enumerate(list_)])
```

Output

```
[-10, -6, -3, -1, 0]
```

Comment: This is O(n^2) though.

Comment: @harshitpatel You welcome, happy to help. It will be appreciated if you can mark the answer.